# Replace tag inside pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to replace some tag in a `pdf` in `java` with parameters :

```java
PDDocument document = null;
document = PDDocument.load(new File("myfile.pdf"))
document = replaceText(document, "$name", "test");
document.save(f.getPath());
document.close();
```

**with replace text :**

```java
for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {

    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
    parser.parse();
    List<?> tokens = parser.getTokens();

    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
        Object next = tokens.get(j);
        if (next instanceof Operator) {
            Operator op = (Operator) next;

            String pstring = "";
            int prej = 0;

            if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                String string = previous.getString();
                string = string.replaceFirst(searchString, replacement);
                previous.setValue(string.getBytes());
            } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                    Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                    if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                        COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                        String string = cosString.getString();

                        if (j == prej) {
                            pstring += string;
                        } else {
                            prej = j;
                            pstring = string;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (searchString.equals(pstring.trim())) {
                    COSString cosString2 = (COSString) previous.getObject(0);
                    cosString2.setValue(replacement.getBytes());

                    int total = previous.size() - 1;
                    for (int k = total; k > 0; k--) {
                        previous.remove(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```

**My problem is this one :**

1. create a word document, add text with $name OR insert a text area $name anywhere then save as pdf file --> it's working but with rendering visual bugs (and I don't what to do that)
2. create a pdf file, add text with adobe reader with the filling tools
   then save --> it's doesn't work.

**How can I detect insert text in a pdf with java/Itext and replace it?**
Or do you have any solutions to do that in `java 1.6`?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to save it as pdf file when you want to modify it later? Pdf doesn't seem like a good approach unless you use PDF forms.

Comment: Hi, yes I need to save it as pdf at the end.

Comment: At the end... so after you fill in the missing data? If you want the intermediary form to be rendered as pdf, then you should use the forms, which you can easily fill via itext: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-acroform-technology
Trying to do some automatic text replacement on a pdf generated from Word doesn't seem like a very robust solution.

Comment: Ok i'll look if it can help me but the file I need to edit is not mine, I retrieve it in his final form and I need to place some info at specific place but I don't want to use coordinates. So I insert text with the filling tools of adobe over the existing pdf to replace it in my code

Comment: It's not working for my problem ...

Comment: Are you sure you got your libraries right? You tagged your question [tag:itext] but your code appears to be using [tag:pdfbox].

Comment: That being said, neither itext nor pdfbox contains a generic text replacement solution out of the box. For both libraries there are code examples but they only work for very special pdfs.

Comment: Yes because I tried differents solutions. Is there any solution to my problem... ? I just need to edit a PDF with my own parameters

Comment: PDF is not a format suitable for editing. Some characters might end up rendered as curves and the text will not be continuous(although it might seem it is). You might find a working solution for one particular pdf generated by one specific version of a renderer, but it will fail when you try it on slightly different pdf. You will never be able to create a robust solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers. Is there a solution with a specific lib to do what I want without using a PDF but with another extension ?